# Saving :content of first post upon topic creation, with Post and Topic models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The new topic form has fields for title, description, and first post content.

Upon submission, a topic with values for title, description, user id, and forum id should be created, along with a post with values for content, user id, and topic id. However, the post's :content is not getting saved to the table, though user id and topic id are.

views/topics/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@topic) do |f| %>
  <% if @topic.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@topic.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this topic from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @topic.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if params[:forum] %><input type="hidden" id="topic_forum_id" name="topic[forum_id]" value="<%= params[:forum] %>" /><% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <textarea name="post[content]" class="form-control" cols="80" rows="20"><%= @post.content %></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

controllers/topics_controller.rb

```
def new
  @topic = Topic.new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  user_id = current_user.id || 1 # temporary assignment until guest account generated
  @topic = Topic.new(title: params[:topic][:title], description: params[:topic][:description], forum_id: params[:topic][:forum_id], user_id: user_id)
  if @topic.save
    @post = Post.new(content: params[:post][:content], topic_id: @topic.id, user_id: user_id)
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created topic."
      redirect_to "/topics/#{@topic.id}"
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  else
    render action: 'new
  end
end
```

models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :replies, :dependent => :nullify

  validates :content, presence: true

  attr_accessor :content
end
```

models/topic.rb

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :forum_id, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Can you post your full form?

Comment: Updated with the full form. It's very basic.

Comment: Can you also post the params log generated while submitting the form?

Comment: Did my answer worked for you ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The post is created, but the :content is still null.

Comment: The command line says that topic_params[:posts_attributes]["0"][:content] contains the post's content. I've tried inserting this value into @post.content (and @topic.posts.first) in a million different ways, but no dice.

Comment: ........ I just had to delete the line "attr_accessor :content" from the Post model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement the concept of `accepsts_nested_attributes` like below to handle your situation.

```
#topic.rb

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :forum_id, presence: true
end

#topics_controller.rb

def new
  @topic = Topic.new
  @post = @topic.posts.build
end

def create
  user_id = current_user.id || 1 # temporary assignment until guest account generated
  @topic = Topic.new(params[:topic])
  if @topic.save
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    @post.topic_id = @topic.id
    @post.user_id = user_id
     if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created topic."
      redirect_to @topic
     else
      render action: 'new'
     end
   else
     render action: 'new'
   end
end

#form
<%= form_for(@topic) do |f| %>
  <% if @topic.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@topic.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this topic from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @topic.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if params[:forum] %><input type="hidden" id="topic_forum_id" name="topic[forum_id]" value="<%= params[:forum] %>" /><% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for @post do |p| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= p.text_area :content, cols: 80, rows: 20, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```